# char** in int main(int argc, char** argv)

Tags: c++

I am watching a video about how to build a Hash table, but from the beginning there is a line that I don't understand:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
```

What does "char**" mean?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: It means a pointer to a pointer to a character. HTH.

Comment: @TonyD thanks, one more thing, isn't that strange to define inputs for the main function?

Comment: @Roshan: no.  When people run a program, they can pass arguments on the command line.  That's what the `argv` is for: `argv[0]` is nominally the name of the program, `argv[1]` is the first space-separated word in the argument list - if any.  Each `argv[i]` entry is a `char*` to an ASCIIZ copy of the word from the command line.  `argc` tells you how many words were on the command line, plus one for the program name.  Every single C++ program that handles command line arguments will have this signature, which is why practically *any* introductory C++ book covers this.

Comment: @TonyD, The explanations was perfect, Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is one of the allowable function signatures for the designated start of the program.

It is a requirement of a C++ executable that it contain one and only one of:

1. `int main()`
2. `int main(int argc, char** argv)` (This function signature of `main` is allowed to take additional parameters.)

You can find more information about `main` here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

To specifically quote the definition of `argv`:

> Pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to null-terminated multibyte strings that represent the arguments passed to the program from the execution environment (`argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]`). The value of `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be ​0​.

For a more detailed documentation of how Microsoft populates `argv` you can see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx